# How to set two fonts for JTextArea in case one is not supported

Tags: java, fonts

In HTML&CSS it is possible to set multiple fonts as it can happen that a different computers may not support all fonts. So you can do something like:

```
/*CSS*/
{
    font-family: consolas, sans-serif, serif;
}
```

So if consolas isn't supported, go with sans-serif.
To set the font in JTextArea i used:

```
textarea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

is there a way to check if the font is supported on the current computer and if not, switch to another one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

---

[java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()) 
[java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts())

This methods returns a list of available system fonts, so you can check if your font is supported

---

If your font is not supported you can use

```
Font.getDefault()
```

This method return the default system font

---

This is an example function to check if your font is supported

```
public static boolean isMyFontSupported(String fontname) {
    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    for (String installedFont : graphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()) {
        if (installedFont.equalsIgnoreCase(fontname)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```